# Issue with Row_Number() Over Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying to reset the row_number when the value changes on Column Value and I have no idea on how should i do this.

This is my SQL snippet:

```
    WITH Sch(SubjectID, VisitID, Scheduled,Actual,UserId,RLev,SubjectTransactionID,SubjectTransactionTypeID,TransactionDateUTC,MissedVisit,FieldId,Value) as
(
select 
    svs.*,
    CASE WHEN stdp.FieldID = 'FrequencyRegime' and svs.SubjectTransactionTypeID in (2,3) THEN
    stdp.FieldID
    WHEN stdp.FieldID is NULL and svs.SubjectTransactionTypeID = 1
    THEN NULL
    WHEN stdp.FieldID is NULL
    THEN 'FrequencyRegime'
    ELSE stdp.FieldID
    END AS [FieldID],
    CASE WHEN stdp.Value is NULL and svs.SubjectTransactionTypeID = 1
    THEN NULL
    WHEN stdp.Value IS NULL THEN
    (SELECT TOP 1 stdp.Value from SubjectTransaction st
        JOIN SubjectTransactionDataPoint STDP on stdp.SubjectTransactionID = st.SubjectTransactionID and stdp.FieldID = 'FrequencyRegime'
        where st.SubjectID = svs.SubjectID
        order by st.ServerDateST desc)
    ELSE stdp.Value END AS [Value]
from SubjectVisitSchedule svs
left join SubjectTransactionDataPoint stdp on svs.SubjectTransactionID = stdp.SubjectTransactionID and stdp.FieldID = 'FrequencyRegime'
)
select 
    Sch.*,
    CASE WHEN sch.Value is not NULL THEN
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Sch.Value, Sch.SubjectID order by Sch.SubjectID, Sch.VisitID)
    ELSE NULL
    END as [FrequencyCounter],
    CASE WHEN Sch.Value = 1 THEN 1--v.Quantity
    WHEN Sch.Value = 2 and (ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Sch.Value, Sch.SubjectID order by Sch.SubjectID, Sch.VisitID) % 2) <> 0
    THEN 0
    WHEN Sch.Value = 2 and (ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Sch.Value, Sch.SubjectID order by Sch.SubjectID, Sch.VisitID) % 2) = 0
    THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
    END AS [DispenseQuantity]
 from Sch
--left join VisitDrugAssignment v on v.VisitID = Sch.VisitID
where SubjectID = '4E80718E-D0D8-4250-B5CF-02B7A259CAC4'
order by SubjectID, VisitID
```

This is my Dataset:
[image: Dataset]

Based on the Dataset, I am trying to reset the FrequencyCounter to 1 every time the value changes for each subject, Right now it does 50% of what I want, It is counting when the value 1 or 2 is found, but when value 1 comes again after value 2 it continues the count from where it left. I want every time the value is changes the count to also start from the beginning.

Comment: You could make that code snippet a lot smaller and include sample data as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to reproduce and test without sample data, but if you want to know how to number rows based on change in column value, next approach may help. It's probably not the best one, but at least will give you a good start. Of course, I hope I understand your question correctly.

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    [Id] int,
    [Subject] varchar(3),
    [Value] int

)
INSERT INTO #Data 
    ([Id], [Subject], [Value])
VALUES
    (1, '801', 1),
    (2, '801', 2),
    (3, '801', 2),
    (4, '801', 2),
    (5, '801', 1),
    (6, '801', 2),
    (7, '801', 2),
    (8, '801', 2)
```

Statement:

```
;WITH ChangesCTE AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE 
            WHEN LAG([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Subject] ORDER BY [Id]) <> [Value] THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END AS [Change]
    FROM #Data
), GroupsCTE AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM([Change]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Subject] ORDER BY [Id]) AS [GroupID]
    FROM ChangesCTE
)
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [GroupID] ORDER BY [Id]) AS Rn
FROM GroupsCTE
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------------
Id  Subject Value   Change  GroupID Rn
--------------------------------------
1   801     1       0       0       1
2   801     2       1       1       1
3   801     2       0       1       2
4   801     2       0       1       3
5   801     1       1       2       1
6   801     2       1       3       1
7   801     2       0       3       2
8   801     2       0       3       3
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. I was trying to do this without using multiple CTEs and looks like there is no way to do this.

Comment: @ACristian24 In may cases multiple CTEs make it easier to break a problem into simpler steps, but it isn't necessary to do so. A handy trick is that you can replace the final `select` in order to see what the steps are doing, e.g. `select * from ChangesCTE;` to see the results of the first step. It makes debugging a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need DENSE_RANK as you are looking for the row number will only change when value changed. The syntax will be as below-

```
WITH your_table(your_column)
AS
(
    SELECT      2   UNION ALL
    SELECT      10  UNION ALL
    SELECT      2   UNION ALL
    SELECT      11
)

SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY your_column) 
FROM your_table
```